# Dualbooting Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1 Pro (I know it's depressing I'm using Windows OSes still) and when I try to shrink the volume I am allowed only 2796 MB even though I have over 800GB available on the HDD. How I can get around this and shrink the volume to 25600 MB or more? Ran Disk Cleanup and Disk Defrag with no further help either. Any suggestions or advice would be very, very much appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

I had just disabled Fast Startup as well. Would this make any difference.

Comment: upload the screenshot of windows disk management utility.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into the Ubuntu live cd and use gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted). You can resize the windows partition, then boot windows and it will auto-run a disk check before login, because it will detect the size change.